# How to vertically and horizontally a div with display flex in Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to center vertically and horizontally a div inside another div.

I have tested this code in various browser: it works as expected in every browser except Safari, in which the div inside is centered horizontally and not vertically. 
How I can I solve this?

```css
.newsletterHome {
    width: 495px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.newsletterHome div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.45em;
}

.newsletterHome a {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    -moz-transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsletterHome">
   <a target="_blank" href="#"><div>SIGN UP FOR OUR NEWSLETTER!</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is usually a vendor-prefix issue. Have you checked with the relevant vendor prefixes in place? [**Prefixed JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/smonoqp4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem:

```
.newsletterHome div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
    font-size: 1.45em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your css:

```
.newsletterHome div {

   display: inline-flex;
   font-size: 1.45em;
   position: absolute;
   top: 90px;
   left: 50px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-decoration: underline;

}
```

This is a kind of manual way of solving the problem, but it works. The "flex" is the problem in my opinion. They don't work the same way in all browsers.